# strange html5 behavior

Tags: xhtml, html

The following html(5) produces a black line at the bottom of the div. This is caused, because the div get's heigher than the contained image. But I wonder why this happens?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="position:absolute; background:#000;">
    <img src="http://images.google.com/intl/de_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" style="height:50px;">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I dont think it's a browser bug, because the result is the same in Firefox, Chrome and Opera. It renders fine when a XHTML doctype is used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

BTW: It does work in html5 too, but only when I set display:block for image. Is this really needed?

Comment: I think Chrome’s inspector lies about the value of the `vertical-align` property when quirks mode is on.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the XHTML doctype as such that changes it, it's more like strict vs transitional.

Using a XHTML 1.0 transitional doctype puts the browser into limited-quirks mode, whereas the HTML5 style doctype selects standards mode. The vertical-align of images is different between the two modes.

You can see the same black line if you use `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`which also puts the browser into standards mode.

There are a number of ways to remove the black line. One is to set the img to `display:block`.
Another is to set the img to `vertical-align:bottom`.

Comment: If only vertical-align is differen, it doesn't explain why the div gets 4px higher than the image. Normally the image should fit exactly, as the div is positioned absolute without any width/height specified. It seems in html5 the browser silently adds some sort of padding at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

The black bar is your background color showing. If you don't want to see the black, one option is to remove the `background:#000` from your div's style attribute.

Also, why are you using height: 50px in your style attribute? If you're trying to resize the image itself, use the height attribute instead.

OPTION 2:

This code seems to also remove the black background form showing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="background:#000;">
    <img src="http://images.google.com/intl/de_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" style="position:absolute; height: 50px;">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added the black color for debugging purposes only (the whole code is to show the problem). But I wonder why XHTML and HTML5 display different?

Comment: Try adding this to the div style: `margin:0;padding:0;border:0;`.